# OO implementation of RFC 2445

Tags: php, rfc2445

**Question**

What [PHP library](http://www.nabber.org/projects/ical/) would you recommend for attaching meeting notices to email?

Preference given to:

- Swift Mailer integration
- Simple Object-Oriented library

**Application**

Scheduling of appointments for medical clinics. After the user books an appointment, it would be great to send the meeting notice to their email address (upon request, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). It is a very nice OO all purpose emailer.

Comment: I've been using it on my website for awhile now, and I have been very happy with it.